# LaTeX commands are displayed

Tags: bug, mathjax

Why can I see both math formulas and their LaTeX commands on Stack Exchange websites?

For example, the following post from *[What is the probability mass function of the scaled Poisson distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240720/what-is-the-probability-mass-function-of-the-scaled-poisson-distribution)*. This is so annoying. I'm using the Google Chrome browser. It is not a problem in Internet Explorer.

[image]

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say you have an error in your latex.

Comment: The LaTeX seems to be fine but I believe we are talking here about MathJax, not LaTeX.

Comment: Can't repro on Chrome 78.0.3904.97 on macOS https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6mHU.png Why is the image green? Do you have a userscript or something running?

Comment: That renders in less than a second on my cellphone, try the **[MathJax FAQ](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/234/51)** on OR.SE - just when it looks like it's finished 5 seconds later the \sum (**E**) resizes. WFM using Chrome or FF.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Answer (score 3):

This is a local glitch on your browser.  It renders fine for me on Chrome 78.0.3904.97 on Windows.  I notice that on this computer (which is pretty old and a bit slow), the MathJax renders in steps: first I see the raw MathJax, then it renders and I see the correct symbols, then it flashes again and all the symbols and equations get larger.  You're probably getting a hiccup during one of the steps.